# jQuery drop-down menu issues, placed arrows on menu links but menu fades away when the arrows are hovered over

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I've implemented a drop-down menu on my website with jQuery and it functions fine, but I wanted to place an arrow on the links that have sub-menus. The issue with this is, once you hover over said arrow as you're "technically" not hovering over the drop-down element anymore the drop-down disappears and reappears again. How can I get around this?

HTML:

```
<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation" style="float:right;" data-topbar>
 <section class="top-bar-section">
  <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) ); ?>
 </section>
  <div class="arrow-left-1"></div>
  <div class="arrow-left-2"></div>
  <div class="arrow-left-3"></div>
  <div class="arrow-left-4"></div>
  <div class="arrow-left-5"></div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.arrow-left-1, .arrow-left-2, .arrow-left-3, .arrow-left-4, .arrow-left-5 {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  border-left: 5px solid #95020a;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  z-index: 900;
}

.arrow-left-1 {
  left: 58%;
  top: 138%;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#menu-item-1837' ).hover(
    function(){
        $(this).children('.sub-menu').fadeIn('medium');
        $('.arrow-left-1').show();
        $('.arrow-left-2').show();
        $('.arrow-left-3').show();
        $('.arrow-left-4').show();
        $('.arrow-left-5').show();
    },
    function(){
        $(this).children('.sub-menu').fadeOut('medium');
        $('.arrow-left-1').hide();
        $('.arrow-left-2').hide();
        $('.arrow-left-3').hide();
        $('.arrow-left-4').hide();
        $('.arrow-left-5').hide();
    }
);
```

Comment: By the way my friend: take a look here https://css-tricks.com/examples/jQueryStop/ for the animation queueing problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the hard-coded arrows and add `:after` pseudo-element to your class `menu-item-has-children`.

You can style the arrow accordingly.

```
.menu-item-has-children::after { 
    content: "";    
    border-top: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
    border-left: 5px solid #95020a;
    float: right;
}
```

To select the hovered class, select like this:

```
.menu-item-has-children:hover::after {
    border-left-color: white;
}
```

You can see a small working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Tarekis/hq8brwk9/).

Comment: Its getting there! They've appeared, its just a case of perfecting their position now. It doesn't seem to affect the jQuery drop-down either which is perfect. Cheers mate. (:

Comment: Exactly what you needed, it seems! My fiddle fixed the height, but that should be the least of the problem.

Comment: Margin-top: -25px sorted it for me, exactly what I needed! Now I just need to make it so the arrow stays on the drop-down menu when you move from the drop-down to the children items. But thanks to your thorough explanation I believe I understand how before and after selectors work now and feel confident doing this myself! Thanks again. (:

Comment: No problem at all! It should stay just there since the class won't be removed; thus the `::after` element should stay, it just won't have the `:hover` CSS properties, as you now no longer hover the parent list.

Comment: Should something like the below work? As the after element only comes back when you move back to the parent list oddly:              
ul.sub-menu li.menu-item-has-children-has-children:hover:before {
 content: "";    
    border-top: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
    border-left: 5px solid #95020a;
    float: right;
}

Comment: Can you please either update your site, or create a JSFiddle for me to inspect, if it's a quick thing (which it is, i assume) i'll just fix that :)

Comment: I've updated the site with the code I mentioned above if you're able to inspect it, I'll create a jsfiddle if easier though! But is li.menu-item-has-children-has-children valid syntax?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107216/discussion-between-clemens-himmer-and-methoxe).

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `:after` or `:before` selectors to add the arrows as the 'content', instead of creating a new div for each one.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_after.asp

**Edit:** Based on your code you're using WordPress - so there would be no need to add Javascript/jQuery to add elements to your submenu.

Look at the code that WordPress creates and use the elements provided to add a CSS arrow.

```
ul.sub-menu li.menu-item-has-children:after {
content:'>';
color:#fff;
}
```

Here's just a small example, but use it to customise your elements.
Hope this helps

Comment: I'm not too sure how this would avoid the hovering issue though? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Oh apologies - still getting used to this - I thought you just point people in the right sort of direction to actually help them figure out the answer, not just give them the straight up copy and paste answer.

Comment: That is the right way to go, but OP has quite a mess in his code, you really should provide a answer on what to do, not just what to use.

Comment: I never asked for a straight copy and paste answer? I was simply asking how that would change anything as it would still be adding the items as elements? Its called theory.

Comment: You don't give them copy and paste answers, but imagine you do not know what to do with any new feature, some guy says it's what you need,  but nothing more, but does that help you? It does not, not thus your answer is very much improvable! :)

Comment: Gavins answer is sufficient and a good way getting around your problem. (still it's not the final solution since you need a better arrow, color and positioning (look for Clemens' answer))

Comment: @GavinThomas that answer is better than the last for sure! +1 for improving :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have found a solution to the problem already cause it seems to be working fine in your website. If not, please let us know.

Comment: It doesn't for me? :(

Comment: Still no luck here, its when you hover over the arrows on the drop-down menu, that's when it bugs out as the cursor is no longer hovering over the arrow

Comment: Well, there has to be some compatibility problem in your code, because I am on the lastest version of Chrome and the submenus dont disappear, even for a moment.

Comment: Also tested on IE Edge now...Latest version...Try using Javascript for the same instaed of jquery if you're facing this problem...for me, i do not see ANY problem in the code or the CSS...I think you just removed the arrows...

Comment: @AruBasu I've resolved the issue now and rated the top answer, cheers for looking anyway mate. You were probably inspecting the page while I was in the process of troubleshooting so you were looking at the time I removed the arrow divs.